# Complex expression in EPA Derivation

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

We're trying to write some compound expressions in the Derivation of the EPA.

We have an entity to manage some alerts. This entity has one field for each type of alert. The issue is that we'd like to add entityId information to the alert text of the field of the entity.

Something like that:

**_____Attribute______________Type_______________Expression**

temperatureAlertMsg----------------String------------------------EV1.entityID+": Over 20"

So, the value of the attibute temperatureAlertMsg in the entity should be: temperatureSensor01: Over 20

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I do not follow  the question.Could you please post your event structure? for EV1? 
You are just looking for string concatentation function? 
In that case, you can take a look at EEP functions (appear in user manual)
:there are different functions for String operations, one of them is "Concut" function.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.